# can't see lighting in openGL

Tags: opengl

I'm new to openGL and I drew a cube, then I place a camera inside the cube.
What I'm trying to achieve now is lighting the cube.
This is how I tried:

```
void draw(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    // Create light components
    GLfloat ambientLight[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat diffuseLight[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8, 1.0f };
    GLfloat specularLight[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat position[] = { -1.5f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f };

    // Assign created components to GL_LIGHT0
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);

    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(PI / 4, 1.f / 1.f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.3f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.f), PI, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
....
....
}
```

But I don't see any lightings

Comment: You should stay away from the Fixed Function Pipeline and begin to learn Modern OpenGL at least version 3.3+ using the appropriate GLSL versions. Using shaders is much more efficient and flexible with modern hardware. Here is a very good reference site for learning OpenGL. http://learnopengl.com/ It will walk you through creating your vertices, indices, normals, applying textures, lighting, creating models with meshes, loading in a texture cube for doing skyboxes and much more.

Answer (score 3):

> But I don't see any lightings

Welcome to the world of the old-and-busted fixed function pipeline. You're using OpenGL as it was done 20 years ago. The mode of illumination you're using is doing the lighting calculations only at the vertex locations and then simply blends the resulting color over the triangles (or quads). Obviously that won't work if there's a lot of change in illumination over the span of a single triangle.

In your case the light source is very close to your cube, so that's not going to work. You should address this by ditching the fixed function pipeline (FFP) and use shaders. Seriously, the FFP has been out of fashion for some 13 years (first GLSL capable GPUs arrived on the market in 2003). FFP has been emulated with shaders created in-situ ever since.

Also (judging from your other questions related to drawing a cube) you don't supply *face normals*. Normals are essential to doing illumination calculations, so you'll have to supply those as well.